# How to iterate over JSValue parsed from JSON String

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, scala-collections

I have a JSON String ,

```
val name : String = "["Client_2","tClient_1","Client_NB"]"
```

I have converted the Json String to JSValue as below using play

```
val json: JsValue  = Json.parse(cells)
```

Output of json : `["IotClient_NB_2","IotClient_NB_1","IotClient_NB"]`

I need to iterate over above JSON String and take string each value out.

Comment: What do you mean by `take string each value out`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way `json.as[List[String]]` (throws exception if `json` is not `JsArray` of `String`)

For example

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

val name : String = """["Client_2","tClient_1","Client_NB"]"""
val json: JsValue  = Json.parse(name)
val list = json.as[List[String]]

import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

scala> name: String = ["Client_2","tClient_1","Client_NB"]

scala> json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = ["Client_2","tClient_1","Client_NB"]

scala> list: List[String] = List(Client_2, tClient_1, Client_NB)
```

Comment: @andrey.ladniyThanks for the answer. i am getting the below compilation [errorError:(65, 12) bad symbolic reference to java.time encountered in class file 'DefaultReads.class'.
Cannot access term time in package java. The current classpath may be missing a definition for java.time, or DefaultReads.class may have been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
    json.as[List[String]].foreach(println)]

Comment: missed or invalid imports (from java not scala package). Example is well compiled in console.

Comment: I suggest adding all necessary `import ...` statements to your answer. Readers of your answer will thank you for it.